# Relations and transitivity.

Tags: relations

Let $R=\{ (a,b) : \  \mid a-b\mid \ \leq1\ \}$ on $\Bbb Z$

Well I know it's reflexive and symmetric and not anti-symmetric, although I don't see why it's not transitive. if $\mid a-b\mid \leq1 \ \land \mid b-c\mid \leq1 \rightarrow \mid a-c \mid\leq1$. I can also define a set $\{ (1,0),(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(1,2),(2,2) \}$ which would imply that it is.

Comment: Counterexample: $|2-3|\leq 1, |3-4|\leq 1$. But $|2-4|\not\leq 1.$

Comment: Yea, this was my bad. I simply didn't look further. I think I've seen too many of these that I've lost it.

Answer (score 4):

You have $(0, 1), (1, 2) \in R$ but do you have $(0, 2) \in R$?

Comment: Gosh, you're right,. Completely useless question.